# Long range wireless RC airplane control

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi, bluetooth

I pretty new to Arduino and I need help to clarify some things.
 First, I want to make an Arduino controlled RC airplane but I don't know what communication module to use. I did some research and found three options. 
1. Hc 12 Bluetooth: It has a decent range of about 
    1.8km, buy suffers from delay(it can't be used on 
     fast rc cars or airplanes)
2. Nrf24I01: About 850m in open space, uses
     2.4ghz which perfect for RC planes but doesn't 
     really work through walls.
3. Lora: has a range of up to 10km but I didn't read on it that much.

So my question is: which one is better to use in a mini uav. I have no problem with mounting an antenna on top of my building. Will any of these work or is it better to use a wifi module connected to a modem which gives it internet access so that I can control the plane over the internet.

Comment: Any standard RC. For long range TBS CrossFire. For standard range (up to 2 km) - any other 2.4 control. Let say Jump[er T16 with any RX. As you new in Arduino I guess you also new in flight controllers SW. So better to start with something already manufactured. Let say legacy (old) ArduPilot was based on Arduino Mega. Sources can be found on APM site.

Comment: Can you pls elaborate more. By the way, I'm on a tight budget.

Comment: i think that HC12 is not a bluetooth module

Comment: you could use a module that uses the cellular phone network

Comment: @Brandy, what do you mean: APM is here: https://github.com/ArduPilot/ardupilot TBS is here: https://www.team-blacksheep.com/shop/cat:cat_crossfire#product_listing Any RC things are expensive except toys

Comment: @jsotola, no. It will not work because of latency. Nothing that has more than 20-40ms delay will never work with UAV (may be with car but on very slow speed).

Comment: i like ESP-NOW; cheap, fast, semi-simple, longer range than raw wifi.

Comment: Regarding "Lora: has a range of up to 10km...", I know this is not your question but, if you are based in the US, there are laws about keeping constant visual contact (line-of-sight) with autonomous aerial vehicles. And usualy, 10 km is very much of out of that range.

Comment: I guess I’ll have to use the ESP for the project. Thanks